# Firebase Performance failed to start trace because it's already been started and stopped

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-performance

I'm trying to create a very simple Firebase Performance trace with the following code:

```
let trace = Performance.startTrace(name: "setup")
setup()
trace?.stop()
```

All I want this trace to do is track how long the setup() function takes to run. It seems to work the first time, but after that, I get this message printed to console: `[Firebase/Performance] Failed to start trace setup because it has already been started and stopped.`

Is this warning something to be concerned about? And if so, what am I doing wrong that's causing this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to be okay.

I'd recommend you to have a look at extra `trace?.start()` calls. E.g. I had the same issue with the following code:

```
let trace = Performance.startTrace(name: "setup")
trace?.start()
setup()
trace?.stop()
```

Function `startTrace(name:)` starts the trace for you and you don't have to do it again.

Comment: Great catch, that was exactly my problem. Thanks!